# Best way to optimize string search oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-text

I have a table like below :

```
create table xx (university varchar2(2), sub_uni varchar2(2), id varchar2(30), name varchar2(80))
```

Which has pk index on `university,sub_uni,id`

I wanted to perform a quick search on the name column which looked something like below:

```
select * from xx where upper(name) like upper('%JOHN%')
```

However as my table contains around 22 million records and the above query does a full table scan it takes around 20-25 seconds.

To optimize the query I now tried to use Oracle Text..

```
CREATE INDEX xx_name ON xx(name) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
```

After the creation of this index the query to filter records takes less than a second

```
select * from xx where contains(name,'JOHN') > 0
```

However as I am unable to locate a lot of documentation on oracle text I am worried/concerned about the other impacts of such index.

for eg. On average 5000 rows are added to this table while 10million are updated on daily basis.

Is there any impact of using Oracle Text in such scenario / is there any other way of speeding up this query.

Also I am unable to specify tablespace in the creation of domain index and when I drop it, it doesnt even show up in recyclebin!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the performance if you create a simple function-based index like this? `CREATE INDEX xx_name ON xx(UPPER(name));`

Comment: @TonyAndrews Hi Tony, I did not try it at all. If you notice I am having wildcard on both sides in the like operator. As per my knowledge it will not help at all. Should I try ?

Comment: A index (either an ordinary index or a function-based index on `UPPER(name)`) will not help when you are using `LIKE` with a starting wildcard as [Oracle cannot use the index in this case](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm#i1058427).

Comment: @pOrinG No, you are right, it won't help